# Select single item in MYSQLdb - Python

Tags: python, mysql-python

I've been learning Python recently and have learned how to connect to the database and retrieve data from a database using MYSQLdb. However, all the examples show how to get multiple rows of data. I want to know how to retrieve only one row of data.

This is my current method.

```
cur.execute("SELECT number, name FROM myTable WHERE id='" + id + "'")
results = cur.fetchall()
number = 0
name = ""
for result in results:
    number = result['number']
    name = result['name']
```

It seems redundant to do `for result in results:` since I know there is only going to be one result.

How can I just get one row of data without using the `for` loop?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`.fetchone()` to the rescue:

```
result = cur.fetchone()
```

Answer (score 1):

use `.pop()`

```
if results:
   result = results.pop() 
   number = result['number']
   name = result['name']
```

Comment: What if the `cur.execute()` didn't return any results? How would `results.pop()` behave?

Comment: @GaryJohnson put them inside a if to check if results if empty or not.